# Media Query for IPad Pro not working in chrome

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries

I have used this media query :

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

but this code isn't working in **chrome ipad pro extension**. please any one help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have misplaced the values. try this :

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (min-device-width: 1366px) and (orientation: landscape) webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

Comment: @shaharyar Yes i have misplaced the values..! Thanks for your help :)